# Eigenvalues of time-dependent matrix bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For each $t \in [0,b]$, let $A(t)$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}(t) \in L^\infty(0,b).$ Suppose I know that the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ for each $t$ are positive.

Can I conclude that the eigenvalues are also in $L^\infty(0,T)$. This is true for $n=2$ for example since I can use the quadratic formula and it works out.

How about general $n$? How do I do that?

Comment: The eigenvalues are  bounded by the norm (assuming a suitable norm), and if the entries are essentially bounded, then the norm will be bounded.

Comment: Agree with copper.hat. Note that the reverse implication does not necessarily hold. Eigenvalues could stay constant, but the matrix entries grow without bound:
$$A(t)=\pmatrix{1&t\cr0&1\cr}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much copper.hat and Jyrki.